# Permanently restrict or limit the files returned by Google Picker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-picker

I know that it is possible to prepopulate the Google Picker search query with terms and thereby limit the results coming back from `Drive`.  For example, I can restrict the file returned by the Google Picker using this: `view.setQuery("title:12345")`;

My question is:  How can I ***permanently*** restrict the files that are returned by the picker so that they will always meet the criteria that I set with `view.setQuery("title:12345")`?  I don't want users to be able to delete the prepopulated search query and then have access to all files in `Drive`.

Is it possible to permanently limit or restrict the files that are returned by the Google Picker?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, try [filing a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: Thanks @Rafa, maybe I should try that.  I have never filed a feature request before.  I'm still surprised that there doesn't seem to be a way to permanently restrict the files that are returned by Google Picker.  I must be approaching the problem wrong.